# How to center the text within the divisions?

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to center the text within the division so that the two text columns aren't right next to each other.

Original:
[image: original]

So that it's like this:
[image: so that its like this]

My code:

````
              <div class="px-80 py-4 grid grid-cols-2 divide-x-4">
                <div className="w/2 flex flex-col">
                  <div class="font-bold text-6xl text-center">+9.7%</div>
                  <p class="text-gray-700 text-4xl text-center">
                    Since Last Quarter
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="w/2 flex flex-col justify-center w-full h-full items-center">
                  <div class="font-bold text-6xl text-center">-11.3%</div>
                  <p class="text-gray-700 text-4xl text-center">YTD</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `grid` and remove the `px-80` and replace it with `flex` and the following code:

```
<div class="flex  p-10 divide-x-2">
  <div class=" flex flex-col  flex-1">
    <div class="font-bold text-6xl text-center font-[roboto]">+9.7%</div>
      <p class="text-gray-700 mt-2 text-2xl text-center font-serif">
        Since Last Quarter
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=" flex flex-col justify-center flex-1 items-center">
      <div class="font-bold text-6xl text-center font-[roboto]">-11.3%</div>
        <p class="text-gray-700 mt-2 text-2xl text-center font-serif">YTD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### Output:

[image]

#### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lQy0rhzhN8)